# CI affected_rows always return 0 even after Updated

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

I use Codeigniter 3.0.6 to build a system.
Usually, I use affected_rows() to check whether my database is updated or not.

```
    function update($id=0,$data=array())
    {
        $this->db->where($this->key, $id);
        $this->db->update($this->table,$data);
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)return TRUE;
        else return FALSE;
    }
```

Problem is if no update found, it will return 0 as well. As I want to differentiate between Updated and No Update in my code, so i use this solution.

```
    function update($id=0,$data=array())
    {
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->where($this->key, $id);
        $this->db->update($this->table,$data);
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            if ($this->db->trans_status() == FALSE) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            return 'No Update';
        }
    }
```

But even after updated affected_rows always return int(0). 
What's the reason? Thank you.

Comment: btw.. you've only one statement, why did you wrap it into transaction??

Comment: @RahulM i want to differentiate between updated and no update, i search for solution online and that's what i get so far...

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using CI 3.0.6 and affected_rows() gives back the correct amount of updated rows.

Can you do a test without the transactions. Something like this ?

```
function update($id)
{
    $this->db->set('field_name', "new_value");
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('table_name');

    $rows = $this->db->affected_rows();

    return $rows;
}
```

Verify if a record is actually been updated in the database. You can check $rows for the update status.

```
if ($rows < 1) {
    // no update
} else {
    // updated
}
```

Comment: is there any problem in CI2 for affected rows because it always give 0 after update query

Answer (score 0):

If you move  `$this->db->affected_rows()` before the `$this->db->trans_complete();` you will get expected count. Because `affected_rows()` check only the last statement which is `$this->db->trans_complete();` in your problem it will be return `0` .

***You can fix this by assign `$this->db->affected_rows()` to another variable before the  `$this->db->trans_complete();` and validate later.***

```
function update($id=0,$data=array())
{
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->where($this->key, $id);
    $this->db->update($this->table,$data);
    $affected_rows = $this->db->affected_rows(); // moved to here from if condition
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    if ($affected_rows > 0) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        if ($this->db->trans_status() == FALSE) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        return 'No Update';
    }
}
```